# Can I kill Shiva of the East and his bodyguard before I go to Blighttown?

Tags: dark-souls

To get the Dark Grain Ring, you need to kill Shiva's bodyguard. Normally people recommend doing this on Blighttown. However, can I do this in Darkroot Forest and still get the Ring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried it personally, but according to [wiki](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/dark-wood-grain-ring) - you can do it in Darkroot Garden:

> Kill the ninja and he will drop this ring. ...
>
> Killing the ninja in Darkroot Garden: A few kicks (or
> a two handed strong attack from the Drake Sword) will send him over
> the edge, killing him. Reload the game to collect the ring.